# iOS SDK application and crashlytics

Tags: sdk, crash, crashlytics

I'm working on an iOS SDK project that will be imported by other apps.

I wish to use Crashlytics in my project.

The question is as follows. If some of our clients who wish to use the SDK also have Crashlytics installed then how does crashlytics behave? Do any conflicts happen?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Party no. This one is a bit old. Now, crashlytics is part of Firebase, not Fabric. I am not sure the way they behave is the same.